# How does the sort method work? Need to understand the source code

Tags: ruby, sorting

I tried to understand the `sort` method used like:

```
(1..10).sort {|a,b| b <=> a}   #=> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

by looking at [its source code](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort):

```
static VALUE
enum_sort(VALUE obj)
{
    return rb_ary_sort(enum_to_a(0, 0, obj));
}
```

but, I cannot understand how sort works. Please help me to understand how it does the sorting.

Comment: Your question is misleading/unclear. Do you want to know how sort works, or do you want to know how the C implementation of sort in MRI works?

Comment: You are looking for [MRI](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/array.c#2385). You can track it down using the source you have. Find rb_ary_sort which then calls rb_ary_sort_bang after duplicating the array...you get the idea.

Comment: @sawa - I need to understand how the source code works. If that makes sense, can you please increase my score to zero points ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time I have questions like this I find that it is helpful to look at the same method definition in Rubinius.  Rubinius is a port of ruby written entirely in ruby which makes it much easier to read(for me, at least).

In this case, `Enumberable#sort` just transforms the `Enumerable` object to an `Array` object then calls `Array#sort`.

In Rubinius, [Array#sort](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/f871e5b83433c9361b9d5e3dca72125d68c16d55/kernel/common/array.rb#L1557) just calls [Array#sortinplace](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/f871e5b83433c9361b9d5e3dca72125d68c16d55/kernel/common/array.rb#L1575) which in turn calls either [Array#isort](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/f871e5b83433c9361b9d5e3dca72125d68c16d55/kernel/common/array.rb#L1948) or [Array#mergesort](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/f871e5b83433c9361b9d5e3dca72125d68c16d55/kernel/common/array.rb#L1825), depending on the array size.

Both isort(insertion sort) and mergesort are common sorting algorithims that will be nearly identical regardless of which language they are written in and can be easily googled to get a better understanding.

Comment: It looks like the question is about MRI. Rubinius is irrelevant.

Comment: OP is new to ruby and just wants to understand how sorting works.  My thought was that the Rubinius method would be easier to understand than the MRI implementation while still explaining the premise.

Answer (score 1):

`1..10` is short for an array with the numbers from 1 to 10 (step size 1).
`|a,b|` picks two numbers from the array and `b <=> a` compares it. It delivers `+1` when `b` is bigger than `a`, `0` when equal or `-1` when smaller, e.g. for `10 <=> 9` the result is `+1`.
Based on that, an ordinary array sort is performed. Honestly, i don't know what sorting algorithm Ruby uses.

Comment: While not a bad explanation you probably should not say 1..10 "is short for an array". This is a Range which is a different Object. Yes it is an object that includes Enumerable methods so Array and Range share methods but they are not the same.

Comment: "i don't know what sorting algorithm Ruby uses." – None. The spec doesn't prescribe one. MRI and YARV use quicksort, I believe, Rubinius uses mergesort and insertion sort, JRuby just calls the Java sort method (which again depends on the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby uses [quicksort](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/util.c#L344) according to the latest source code